# MongoDb: Delete index of an array within another array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Assuming the following structure:

```
{
  'Tests': [ // Top Array
     {
        'Name': 'A',
         'Data': [ // Second Array
             {
                'Fact': '1'
             }
          ]
     }
  ]
}
```

When I try t to remove any `Fact` matching the value `1`, I write the following query and it works!

> This query is run using the C# driver

```
{$pull: {Tests: {Data: {Fact: '1'}}}}
```

The problem here is that, although it removes `Fact: 1`, the parent of the object is also deleted which in this case leave the `Tests` array empty.

In order to ditch this problem, I tried to change my query to:

```
{$pull: {'Tests.Data.Fact': '1'}}
```

Or

```
{$pull: {'Tests.$.Data.Fact': '1'}} // and also {$pull: {'Tests.Data.$.Fact': '1'}}
```

Or

```
{$pull: {'Tests.$.Data.$.Fact': '1'}}
```

but all failed.

The question is, what is the syntax that I should follow if I only and only want the `Fact: '1'` to be removed and get the following result:

```
{
  'Tests': [ // Top Array
     {
        'Name': 'A',
         'Data': [ // Second Array
             {
                //Empty
             }
          ]
     }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using MongoDB > v3.6 you can use the ["all positional operator" $[]](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/) to achieve that:

```
db.collection.update({}, { $pull: { "Tests.$[].Data": { "Fact": "1" } } })
```

**UPDATE** in response to your comment:

If you want to pull **all matching instances** from the first matching entry in the `Tests` array then this can be done like so:

```
db.collection.update({"Tests.Data": { $elemMatch: { "Fact": "1" } } }, { $pull: { "Tests.$.Data": { "Fact": "1" } } })
```

Let's look at the following example document:

```
{
    "Tests" : [ 
        {
            "Name" : "A",
            "Data" : [
                { 'Fact': '1' }, // first matching entry in "A"
                { 'Fact': '1' }, // second matching entry in "A"
                { 'Fact': '2' },
             ]
        },
        {
            "Name" : "B",
            "Data" : [
                { 'Fact': '1' }, // first matching entry in "B"
                { 'Fact': '1' }, // second matching entry in "B"
                { 'Fact': '2' },
             ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Running the above query once will give you this:

```
{
    "Tests" : [ 
        {
            "Name" : "A",
            "Data" : [
                // all matching items gone from "A"
                { 'Fact': '2' }
             ]
        },
        {
            "Name" : "B",
            "Data" : [
                { 'Fact': '1' }, // first matching entry in "B"
                { 'Fact': '1' }, // second matching entry in "B"
                { 'Fact': '2' }
             ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Running this a second time will wipe out all instances from `"B"`, too.

```
{
    "Tests" : [ 
        {
            "Name" : "A",
            "Data" : [
                // all matching items gone from "A"
                { 'Fact': '2' }
             ]
        },
        {
            "Name" : "B",
            "Data" : [
                // all matching items gone from "B"
                { 'Fact': '2' }
             ]
        }
    ]
}
```

If, however, you want to update only the **very first matching instance** inside the first matching entry in the `Tests` array then I do not think this can be done in a single operation. However, here's a bit of a hack that appears to work:

```
db.collection.update({"Tests.Data": { $elemMatch: { "Fact": "1" } } }, { $set: { "Tests.$.Data.0": { "delete_me": 1 } } }) // this will set the first found { Fact: "1" } document inside the Tests.Data arrays to { delete_me: 1 }
db.collection.update({}, { $pull: { "Tests.$[].Data": { "delete_me": 1 } } }) // this will just delete the marked records from all arrays
```

Running this query once will yield this:

```
{
    "Tests" : [ 
        {
            "Name" : "A",
            "Data" : [
                // first matching item gone from "A"
                { 'Fact': '1' }, // second matching entry in "A"
                { 'Fact': '2' }
             ]
        },
        {
            "Name" : "B",
            "Data" : [
                { 'Fact': '1' }, // first matching entry in Name "B"
                { 'Fact': '1' }, // second matching entry in Name "B"
                { 'Fact': '2' }
             ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The next time you run this, again, another entry will be deleted:

```
{
    "Tests" : [ 
        {
            "Name" : "A",
            "Data" : [
                // all matching items gone from "A"
                { 'Fact': '2' }
             ]
        },
        {
            "Name" : "B",
            "Data" : [
                { 'Fact': '1' }, // first matching entry in Name "B"
                { 'Fact': '1' }, // second matching entry in Name "B"
                { 'Fact': '2' }
             ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Third run:

```
{
    "Tests" : [ 
        {
            "Name" : "A",
            "Data" : [
                // all matching items gone from "A"
                { 'Fact': '2' }
             ]
        },
        {
            "Name" : "B",
            "Data" : [
                // first matching item gone from "B"
                { 'Fact': '1' }, // second matching entry in Name "B"
                { 'Fact': '2' }
             ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And finally, fourth run:

```
{
    "Tests" : [ 
        {
            "Name" : "A",
            "Data" : [
                // all matching items gone from "A"
                { 'Fact': '2' }
             ]
        },
        {
            "Name" : "B",
            "Data" : [
                // all matching items gone from "B"
                { 'Fact': '2' }
             ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I defined to the query to only remove the first encounter (item matching the condition) ?

Comment: Amazing, thank you very very much indeed for the fantastic answer.

Answer (score 0):

The $pull expression applies the condition to each element of the array as though it were a top-level document.Hence, it will Test array to null.
To overcome this we would need some scripting.Assuming that the collection name is **TestArray** following javascript would work on the mongo shell :

```
db.TestArray.find({"_id":2}).forEach(function(doc){
    var TestArray = doc.Test ;
    for (var i =0 ; i < TestArray.length ; i++) {
        DataArray = TestArray[i].Data;
        for (var j =0 ; j < DataArray.length ; j++) {
            DataElement = DataArray[j];
            if (DataElement.fact == 1 )
                DataArray.splice(j,1) ;
    }
}
db.TestArray.save(doc); });
```

The above code looks for the nested element fact and then uses splice operator to remove that element from the inner array.Finally, the modified document is being saved to collection.